# Is there a resource to reveal all keyboard key codes associated with my keyboard?

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard

Recently, I opened up Notepad and let my one year old daughter have a blast typing random gibberish to her hearts content.  She then proceeded to press some magical combinations of the windows key, alts and ctrls that did some interesting things that I was scared I wouldn't be able to recover from.  So, I got to thinking I ought to be able to run a simple Python script that would temporarily block all keys except for the alphanumeric ones.  I want to be able to toggle the blocking or unblocking with a key combination that is unlikely for her to press on her own (like ctrl+esc+del or something), but otherwise make all the F keys, windows key, etc have no effect.  I found the keyboard module on PyPI, and it seems like it contains the functionality I need; however, I would need to know how to address each key on my keyboard in order to code the program to do what I want, and I cant figure out how to do that.  I ran a simple code snippet which I think is close, but I don't know exactly what it is telling me:

```
import keyboard


keys = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',
        '`', '-', '=', '[', ']', '\\', ';', '\'', ',', '.', '/',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for key in keys:
    print(key, '\t', keyboard.key_to_scan_codes(key))
```

It returns a series of tuples, most having only one value, but others having two:

```
1    (2, 79)
2    (3, 80)
3    (4, 81)
...
x    (45,)
y    (21,)
z    (44,)
```

I suspect that I can enter one of the codes in the block method, which would prevent that key from being pressed, but the problem is I don't want to block these keys, I want to block all of the other ones, and I don't know how to find the code for the F5 key, for example.  I obviously cant type it into my script to get the code, and various online references have several different numbers for these keys, some of which I can tell are incorrect because they overlap with the key codes I can see by running my script.  I also don't know how to tell it to differentiate between the numpad keys, and the numbers above the 'qwerty' keys, for example.  Is there a better way to do what I want?  I feel like this shouldn't be that hard of a task, but I am stuck at a brick wall...  Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: This site may have your answer [Appendix B. Keyboard Key Code Values](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/DHTML_javascript/0596004672_jvdhtmlckbk-app-b.html)

Comment: I had found that previously, but the return from my script above does not match those values, so I am not sure this is the key unfortunately...

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples of the return code from your keys?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, busy few days at work... I edited my question to include a snippet of the return code.  I can copy paste the whole output if that helps, just didn't want to make my question super long just to include all of those keys lol...